# Using Unicode with TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

I want to use Malayalam (an Indian language) fonts in a PDF file from a PHP application. How can I use Unicode fonts in TCPDF?

Comment: Sure. Just set your PHP encoding first.

Comment: Hi 'Cole9', Can you explain it ? Sorry I didnt understand. Anyway thanks for the quick response

Comment: You need to set your PHP encoding to be UTF-8.

Comment: @Cole Please explain how to "set your PHP encoding".

Comment: @JEM If you don't embed the font in the PDF itself, it *should* work very simply, but the result will depend on the capabilities of the PDF viewer reading the file. If you want to embed the font, you need a font that works with TCPDF. This can be very tricky; I have done this for Japanese and it was tricky enough to find a free font that actually worked. A lot of trial and error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `$unicode` parameter on the **TCPDF** constructor to false and the `$encoding` parameter to 'ISO-639-2'([Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-2_codes) says)

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, false, 'ISO-639-2', false);
```

or if the above doesn't work and if you got the malayalam font, set it this way.

```
$fontname = $pdf->addTTFfont('/path-to-font/malayalam.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
```

**[Source](http://www.tcpdf.org/fonts.php)**

Comment: If you set the encoding to ISO-8859, Malayalam will most certainly not work. "Some other character map" will, but why not stick to Unicode to begin with?

Comment: @deceze, Seems like there is no unicode for this font. http://hackingtom.wordpress.com/2012/05/12/unicodemalayalam/

Comment: Nowhere does it say there are ***no*** Unicode fonts for Malayalam. In fact, my Mac OS X comes with several Unicode Malayalam fonts.

Comment: Found something interesting on wiki and i have updated the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry to report that you have no idea what you're talking about. ISO-639 is a standard specifying just *codes* for languages, e.g. "en" for "English". It is not in any way an *encoding*.

Comment: Any turnarounds for this ?

Comment: As I said in the comment underneath the question, Unicode/UTF-8 encoded text is a good starting point. The trick is finding a font (your "malayalam.ttf") that works with TCPDF. I don't have one at hand and I'm not going to google for one, the OP can do that himself.

Comment: @Shankar: These things are not working. Did you use Unicode fonts in TCPDK? I want to use Thoolika.ttf which is already there in TCPDF Font directory. If you done it already, kindly show the code

Answer (score 0):

The **addTTFfont** method is now in the **include/tcpdf_fonts.php** file in the **TCPDF_FONTS** class.

Hence the following will be needed to include a font after generating the font description files from the font placed in the **fonts** folder:

```
$fontname = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('./fonts/latha.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
$pdf->SetFont($fontname, '', 14, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download Unicode fonts you like for example malayalam.ttf as an example
then copy the font file just the **malayalam.ttf** then paste it inside

- tcpdf\fonts

then inside the file you want to show all information with that font, you need to type

```
$fontname = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('../fonts/malayalam.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
$pdf->SetFont($fontname, '', 14, true);
```

**Note)** Probably some of the fonts that you have downloaded will be displaying unexpected symbols like ?/^& then you have to try another font because the used font perhaps it's not a properly Unicode font type.